# How smart is the firestore update protocol

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am implementing an application that updates a document each second.

All connected users are listening to this document.

The document that I update is quite big (ca 40k as json) but most of the times I am only updating a single field in that document.

So I wonder if I should break this data out into its own document or if the protocol that firebase/firestore uses is smart? I.e. so that it only sends out the modifified data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore client sends the data that you pass to the API call. So if you call `documentRef.update()` with a single field, it sends just the path to the document and that field. If you call `documentRef.set()` or `.update()` with more fields, it passes the path and those fields.

Comment: Ok I currently send the entire json. I have to change this then. Thanks!

Comment: I have changed this but have not verified that it works. Not sure how to do that :-)

Anyhow the values in the firestore console flips and I wonder why. It seems like only the field that I am updating is flashing red byt why are some other fields changing. See video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vpSBSsELJMoBWm3pMduVUCYmuhftKPVs/view?usp=sharing

I.e. fixedChips and payout fields.

Comment: Sorry, but that is really hard to troubleshoot on. Your question here was how Firestore worked in general, which I think is still covered in this answer. If you're having a concrete problem in your implementation then I recommend opening a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy/paste to reproduce the problem.